# Pandas: count dots in a string - same as length?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of dots in an email address using Python + Pandas.

The first record is "addison.shepherd@gmail.com". It should count 2 dots. Instead, it returns 26, the length of the string.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://profalibania.com.br/python/EmailsDoctors.xlsx"
docs = pd.read_excel(url)

docs["PosAt"] = docs["Email"].str.count('.')
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sees the dot as a regex.

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html - *"Valid regular expression."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) takes a regex expression as input. To match a literal period (`.`), you must escape it:

```
docs["Email"].str.count('\.')
```

Just specifying `.` will use the regex meaning of the period (matching any single character)

Answer (score 3):

The [**`.str.count(..)`** method [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) works with a [*regular expression* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This is specified in the documentation:

> This function is used to count the number of times a particular **regex pattern** is repeated in each of the string elements of the `Series`.

For a regex, the dot means "all characters except new line". You can use a *character set* (by surrounding it by square brackets):

```
docs["PosAt"] = docs["Email"].str.count('[.]')
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant here would be to compare the length of the original email column with the length of that column with all dots removed:

```
docs["Email"].str.len() - docs["Email"].str.replace("[.]", "").len()
```